# Failed to retrieve related layout via metadata namespace

Tags: apex, metadata, summer-17

Wondering if anyone has actually tried Metadata namespace. I have tried the following code in anonymous block in my sandbox:

```
Metadata.layout attachmentLayout =  new Metadata.layout();
List<String> layoutList = new List<String>{'Account-Account Layout.layout'};

List<Metadata.Metadata> components = Metadata.Operations.retrieve(Metadata.MetadataType.Layout, layoutList);
attachmentLayout = (Metadata.layout)components.get(0);

List<Metadata.RelatedListItem> relatedLists = attachmentLayout.relatedLists;
```

However, this doesn't work. I am getting index out of bound exception. And the reason, of course is it failed to retrieve the account layout. Anyone knows how to fix this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You don't include the "extension", but instead specify it exactly as you would in package.xml:

```
Metadata.layout attachmentLayout =  new Metadata.layout();
List<String> layoutList = new List<String>{'Account-Account Layout'};

List<Metadata.Metadata> components = Metadata.Operations.retrieve(Metadata.MetadataType.Layout, layoutList);
attachmentLayout = (Metadata.layout)components.get(0);

List<Metadata.RelatedListItem> relatedLists = attachmentLayout.relatedLists;
```